# generate temp gpg key non interactively (unattended mode)

Tags: github-actions, gnupg, maven-gpg-plugin

**Specific problem:**

Unable to create required files in `gnupg` home directory, so gpg couldn't connect the agent.

**Additional details:**

1. With the help of [`gnupg docs`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html), I generated a temporary key.

```yaml
- name: gpg key generation - transient
      run: >
        export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)"
        cat >tempkey <<EOF
          %echo Generating a basic OpenPGP key
          Key-Type: DSA
          Key-Length: 1024
          Subkey-Type: ELG-E
          Subkey-Length: 1024
          Name-Real: J143 Bot
          Name-Comment: this contains some passphrase
          Name-Email: j143+[bot]@protonmail.com
          Expire-Date: 0
          Passphrase: asdfghjkl
          # Do a commit here, so that we can later print "done" :-)
          %commit
          %echo done
        EOF
        gpg --batch --generate-key tempkey
```

2. tried this key generation in github actions (CI), I am having the following error messages:

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/runner/gnupg_home'
gpg: failed to create temporary file '/home/runner/gnupg_home/.#lk0x00005632ca729d00.fv-az269-930.1622': Permission denied
gpg: keyblock resource '/home/runner/gnupg_home/pubring.kbx': Permission denied
gpg: Generating a basic OpenPGP key
gpg: failed to create temporary file '/home/runner/gnupg_home/.#lk0x00005632ca732190.fv-az269-930.1622': Permission denied
gpg: can't connect to the agent: Permission denied
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No agent running
gpg: key generation failed: No agent running
gpg: done
```

3. The generated key is used for signing with `maven-gpg-plugin`, the error message looks like this:

```sh
[INFO] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:1.6:sign' with basic configurator -->
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) ascDirectory = /home/runner/work/release-scripts/release-scripts/systemds/target/gpg
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) defaultKeyring = true
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) homedir = /home/runner/gnupghome
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) interactive = false
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) passphraseServerId = gpg.passphrase
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: org.apache.systemds:systemds:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/runner/work/release-scripts/release-scripts/systemds/pom.xml
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) settings = org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter@596ad7fe
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[INFO] [DEBUG]   (f) useAgent = true
[INFO] [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] [DEBUG] Generating signature for /home/runner/work/release-scripts/release-scripts/systemds/target/systemds-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Complete workflow file here: [`./maven-publish.yml#L43-L98`](https://github.com/j143/release-scripts/blob/e461ea2b922655585367c258e683025a7fec09f7/.github/workflows/maven-publish.yml#L43-L98)

Comment: I did not use `sudo` because gpg keys won't be passed between modes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.